# migrate all logical volumes (including swap and /) to a new disk

Tags: migration, oracle-linux

The current setup on my Oracle Linux Server release 5.8:

```
/dev/sda2 (30GB)
Logical volume  /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00    / 
Logical volume  /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol02    /home/app/oracle 
Logical volume  /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol04    /home/app/oracle/product/weblogic 
Logical volume  /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol03    /home/app/work
Logical volume  /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01    swap 

/dev/sdb1 (60GB)
Logical volume  /dev/VolGroup01/Log2Vol00   /home/app/work/test/attachment 
Logical volume  /dev/VolGroup01/backup      /backup 

/dev/sdc1 (5GB)
Logical volume  /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00    / 

/dev/sdd1 (5GB)
Logical volume  /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol04    /home/app/oracle/product/weblogic
```

As you can see there are 2 volume groups (`VolGroup00` and `VolGroup01`) and 4 disks (`sda2`, `sdb1`, `sdc1` and `sdd1`). Now I want to move `sda2`, `sdc1` and `sdd1` to a new disk and remove the old disks.

I was thinking about the following procedure:

1. Create two new disks (one of 80GB and one of 120GB)
2. extend `VolGroup00` with the 80GB disk and extend `VolGroup01` with the 120GB disk with `vgextend`
3. move the filesystems from the old disk to the new disk with `pvmove`
4. remove the old disks from the volumegroup with `vgreduce`

However, I'm having doubts about moving the swap and the / filesystem because I think it quite risky to move the core of the server to another disk. Is there any way that I can move those without chance of demolishing the server itself?

Comment: Are you talking about a live migration while the server is up, running and doing work? Are there raid configurations involved? You don't have to move the swap partition. Just replace it with another one.

Comment: i was thinking about live migration indeed but the server can be brought down if necessary. Good point about the swap, didn't think of that! No raid configuration

Comment: Then your task should be as easy as the second result when googling for "lvm online migration" http://www.tecmint.com/lvm-storage-migration/

Comment: this look amost OK, have you thought about boot section (likely in /dev/sda1) ?

Comment: @Bananguin: I did indeed find that link but it doesn't specify anything about moving your /. I'm probably too careful but I wanted a specific yes or no.

Comment: @Archemar boot section is indeed in /dev/sda1 when I check it with fdisk -l. That shouldn't be a problem if I'm correct?

Comment: as long as you don't remove device underlaying /dev/sda ...

Comment: @Noosrep: if the "how" is not a problem anymore, then, yes, this should be quite possible. I did it once myself, but that was on a completely idle server. I don't know if there can be "unlucky" timings where things hit the fan when removing the old pv. To be safe I'd suggest you remount root as readonly, but it appears `/var` is on the root partition as well.

Comment: @Archemar I was thinking about creating a new /dev/sda1 on the new disk with pvcreate and then remove the old disk

Comment: your new disk will be /dev/sde /dev/sdf, create a partition on /dev/sde (sde1) and instruct BIOS to boot on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can mirror the lvs, break them after the copy, test (with a reboot) and remove the data from the old disks. Just don't mirror the swap fs, it's better to create another.

In this [link](http://missoulapcspecialist.com/techblog/linux-lvm-boot-mirroring-boot-disk-migration-debian/) the guy has a case where he mirrors the root fs. He does for the swap, but is much better not to. There are addional steps related to the fstab and grub, wich are important for your machine to be able to boot from the new drives.

The advantage is that you can go back to the old disks at any point of the process. So don't remove the lv's from the other disks before you have everything working fine on the new disks.

You can test by setting the boot to your new disks.